# Disable notification about time invalid in this period in ngx-mat-timepicker

Tags: angular

In Angular 12
I use ngx-mat-timepicker to set time. I set min time is 5 AM for it so it can't choose  1:38 AM. When I choose 1:38 PM it is available but when I choose AM it pop up a notification "Current time would be invalid in this period".
I want to disable this notification. I just want it can't click

[image]

I was read document in here but it seem no information about it.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-timepicker#ngxMatTimepickercomponent
I was used  `[enableInvalidTime]="false"` like Chat GPT suggested and it didn't work

Comment: You'll notice that on the link you shared there is no `enableInvalidTime` option listed at all.  Don't use Chat GPT for programming help, it doesn't know specifics about programming or angular libraries.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.